# Knockoutjs visible binding with || or?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to do something basic like:

```
data-bind="visible: x || y"
```

showing if either x or y is set to true

Everything I've tried has failed so far though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` and `y` are observable properties then you need to call them as methods:

```
data-bind="visible: x() || y()"
```

Answer (score 0):

When using observables in a formula like that, you need to call them as functions.

```
data-bind="visible: x() || y()"
```